# Implementing clustering algorithms in Neo4j

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, cluster-analysis

I need to extend Neo4j. 
Is it possible to implement for example MLC algorithm? Or maybe there already are some implementations.

Thanks

Comment: Stefan's answer is probably the best that's possible.   You might consider adding details on what approach you'd like to try, or what you've tried to date.  Of course if you have a general purpose programming language like java or python and a graph database, of course it's possible to implement a graph algorithm, but that's not much to go on.

Comment: You can also have a look at this, it is still WIP but a good starting point: https://github.com/maxdemarzi/graph_processing and there is also https://github.com/besil/Neo4jSNA

Answer (score 4):

Since your question is rather vague, so is my answer.

Yes you can extend Neo4j with your custom code, look into [unmanaged extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) for details.

In addition to the well known features of `GraphAlgoFactory` there's some code regarding centrality which is not part of the public API, see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/centrality